# How to block yandex

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, yandex

I'm trying to block yandex from my site. I've tried the solutions posted in other threads but they are not working so I'm wondering if I am doing something wrong?

The user-agent string is:

```
    Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; YandexBot/3.0; +http://yandex.com/bots
```

I have tried the following (one at a time). RewriteEngine is on

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^yandex.com$" bad_bot_block
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from env=bad_bot_block
    Allow from ALL

    SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^yandex.com$" bad_bot_block
    <RequireAll>
    Require all granted
    Require not env bad_bot_block       
    </RequireAll>
```

Can anyone see a reason one of the above won't work or have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else has this problem, the following worked for me:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*(yandex).*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Comment: Your regex can be simplified... `^.*(yandex).*$` is the same as simply `yandex` (no need for the capturing subpattern). And `.*` can be reduced to `^` (`.*` is comparatively inefficient since it forces a traversal of the entire URL-path.) The `L` flag is not required when used with `F` - it is _implied_. The `NC` flag on the _condition_ would not seem to be required (forcing a case-insensitive match is again less efficient).

Comment: Thanks once again. I will make those changes. Regarding the NC flag, there will be other bots to block and I'm not sure of the case used so I thought it safer to use that flag. I know I can look it up in the user-agent string but I'm trying to make this automatic in the code.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^yandex.com$" bad_bot_block
> ```

With the *start* and *end-of-string* anchors in the regex you are bascially checking that the User-Agent string is exactly equal to "yandex.com" (except that the `.` is *any* character), which clearly does not match the stated user-agent string.

You need to check that the `User-Agent` header *contains* "YandexBot" (or "yandex.com"). You can also use a case-sensitive match here, since the real Yandex bot does not vary the case.

For example, try the following instead:

```
SetEnvIf User-Agent "YandexBot" bad_bot_block
```

Consider using the `BrowserMatch` directive instead, which is a shortcut for `SetEnvIf User-Agent`.

If you are on Apache 2.4 then you should be using the `Require` (second) variant of your two code blocks. `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives are Apache 2.2 and formerly deprecated on Apache 2.4.

However, consider using using `robots.txt` instead to block *crawling* in the first place. [Yandex supposedly supports `robots.txt`](https://yandex.com/support/webmaster/robot-workings/user-agent.html).

Comment: The .com you mentioned was the problem but I still couldn't get it to work with either of the methods I showed. Instead I used rewrite as shown and that worked. Thank you for pointing out the mistake. Also, regarding the robots file, yandex doesn't honor it. It was one of the first things I tried.

Comment: "but I still couldn't get it to work" - You likely have a conflict with other directives. For instance, if you have mod_rewrite directives that trigger a second (or more) pass(es) through the rewrite engine then the env var is renamed with a `REDIRECT_` prefix and you will need to check for `REDIRECT_bad_bot_block` instead. (Although this can often be avoided by modifying your existing directives, which may require Apache 2.4.)